# Coloring a `cat` output?

Tags: shell-script

I'm trying to practice code and integrating my other interests with it, and a strong interest of mine is genetics/science in general. I'm making a simple script to generate a random string, but if I use the input for a genetic code (AGCT), the `cat` output will be colored according to the letters (A - blue, G - green, C - red, T - yellow). I was scratching my head for a while on it, and my google-fu isn't very good. An output from the command (using the genetic code input) looks like this:

```
user@conroe$ random AGCT 128
TTCAGGATCAGGTGGCCGATGCCCGTCACGTAGTGGAGGTATTACGTTTTCATCAATCACACGTTACCCCACTTCCTAGCGACAACGTGTGACTCGATGAATAGGAGCAGCGTCCCGCTCGAGATGAC
```

And this is the code:

```
RED='\033[0;31m'
NC='\033[0m'
if [ $# == 2 ]
then
    { cat /dev/urandom | env LC_CTYPE=C tr -dc $1 | head -c $2; echo; }
    else
        printf "${RED}error: ${NC}insufficient input\n"
fi
```

Any help?

Comment: You can just pipe to `sed` as:
`random AGCT 128 | sed "s/A/${BLUE}A${NC}/" | sed "s/G/${GREEN}G${NC}/"` and so on ...

Comment: I'm not sure if I understand what you want to do. You want to color the output to the letter A with blue, G with green and so on?

Comment: @SaulOrtega Yep!

Comment: Why the superfluous `cat`? You should just do `< /dev/urandom env LC_TYPE=C tr -dc $1 | ....`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can pipe the output of `< /dev/urandom tr -dc $1 | head -c $2` (I took the liberty of removing the [UUOC](http://catb.org/jargon/html/U/UUOC.html) and the apparently unneeded `env LC_CTYPE=C` and `echo`; you can restore them in your version however) to a `while` loop reading one character at the time and echoing different color escape sequences followed by a different character based on the read character:

```
#!/bin/bash

if [ $# == 2 ]
then
    < /dev/urandom tr -dc $1 | head -c $2 | while read -n 1 x
    do
        case $x in
            A)
                echo -ne '\033[0;34mA'
            ;;
            G)
                echo -ne '\033[0;32mG'
            ;;
            C)
                echo -ne '\033[0;31mC'
            ;;
            T)
                echo -ne '\033[0;33mT'
            ;;
        esac
    done
    echo -e '\033[0m'
    exit 0
fi
exit 1
```

[image: screenshot]

Comment: Don't hardcode escape sequences, use `tput` which gets them from the current terminal definition: `tput setaf 4; echo -n A`, `tput setaf 2; echo -n G`, etc...

Comment: It works, but I was looking for something that was only in one line. This splits it up and prints a new character each line.

Comment: @ViktorAhlström This prints everything in only one line followed by a single newline at the end. Are you sure you copied the script exactly like it is? Also it's meant to be run in `bash`. Which shell are you using?

Comment: I'm using zsh, oops.

Comment: Ok, thanks, if I run it in bash using `bash random AGCT 16; exit` then it will work.

Comment: @Celada It's more complicated that that.  On OpenBSD: `tput setaf 3` - `tput: not enough arguments (3) for capability \`setaf'`; `echo $TERM` - `xterm-256color`; `infocmp -1 | grep setaf` - `setaf=\E[%?%p1%{8}%<%t3%p1%d%e%p1%{16}%<%t9%p1%{8}%-%d%e38;5;%p1%d%;m,`

Comment: @ViktorAhlström Just `bash random AGCT 16` will do. If this does it for you you can accept this answer, however if you need a `zsh` solution I can't help.

Comment: @ViktorAhlström In any case you can run `chmod +x random` to mark the script as executable; this way you can run it just by running `./random`.

Comment: I know this may be a bit extensive, but I'm wondering if it's possible, I'm wondering if you can make it so the characters print out one by one so you can see the sequence forming. Is that possible?

Comment: @lcd047 ah, too bad. Thanks for the correction. I guess I wish `tput` worked better/more portably than it does :-(

Comment: @ViktorAhlström Not that much, actually this is what it does already, altough it's so fast that you probably can't see it. Just add a `sleep 1` or `sleep <whatever_number>` statement after the `case` statement (i.e. after the `esac` line).